# how is bellman ford algorithm useful in networks?

Tags: networking, dijkstra, bellman-ford

Dijkstra's algorithm is more efficient than bellman algorithm still we use bellman ford algo for negative edges but what do these negative edges even represent in networks?
I couldn't find answer to this question anywhere and this question is killing me, i just need a few applications so i can feel that it is really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bellman-Ford algorithm is used by DVR protocols like RIP and RIPv2.

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

> Negative edge weights are found in various applications of graphs,
>   hence the usefulness of this algorithm.[2] If a graph contains a
>   "negative cycle", i.e., a cycle whose edges sum to a negative value,
>   then there is no cheapest path, because any path can be made cheaper
>   by one more walk through the negative cycle. In such a case, the
>   Bellman–Ford algorithm can detect negative cycles and report their
>   existence, but it cannot produce a correct "shortest path" answer if a
>   negative cycle is reachable from the source

Comment: my principle doubt is that i don't know the physical existence of negative edge.

Comment: usually the cost is measured as number of hops
how can it be ever negative